# Missing attributes with Facebook Graph API Photo Node

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an *access token* with the `manage_pages` scope. Using this token, I call the endpoint [specified here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#Reading) (`GET /{page-id}/photos?type=uploaded`).

The result is for some reason lacking all attributes except *id* and *created_time*. This is a part of the response:

```
"data": [
  {
    "created_time": "2018-10-30T18:12:31+0000",
    "id": "1172525292900120"
  },
  {
    "created_time": "2018-10-30T18:10:08+0000",
    "id": "1172524459566870"
  }
]
```

The docs says that *data* should contain "A list of Photo nodes". Looking at [the photo node docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/), it seems they have exactly what you'd expect.

My app does not have the permission `Page Public Content Access` yet. But according to their App Review section, it isn't needed for accessing my own page's content. And then again, I wouldn't even be able to get a list of photos if I didn't have access to the page.

> While you are testing your app and before you submit it for review, your app can only access content on a Page for which the following is true: The person who holds the admin role for the Page also holds an admin, developer, or tester role on the app.

Why am I missing some attributes in the Photo nodes?

Comment: You have to specify which fields you want

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to specify which fields to retrieve like this: `GET /{page-id}/photos?type=uploaded&fields=images`.